# Highlight selected item onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im trying to set a selected item state to true when I click it, an once I click in a different one, set it to false and set the new clicked one to true.
So far my setActiveItem hook is returning or unidentified or never changes the state.

```
const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(false);

    //                          setActiveItem={setActiveItem}

    const onClick = (item) => {
        setActiveItem(true);
        console.log(item);
    };
    if (!options || !options.length) {
        return false;
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.main}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
                <View style={styles.titleContainer} />
                <FlatList
                    key={options.value}
                    data={options}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                        <TextComponent
                            {...otherProps}
                            onTypeFilterChange={onTypeFilterChange}
                            style={styles.item}
                            type={item.value || ALL_MEDIA_TYPES}
                            title={item.label}
                            item={item}
                            setActiveItem={() => onClick(item.selected)}
                            // isActive={activeItem === true}
                        >
                            {item.value}
                        </TextComponent >
                    )}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
```

And on my TextComponent:

```
const TextComponent = ({
    type,
    title,
    onTypeFilterChange,
    item,
    isActive,
    setActiveItem,
}) => {
    const onTextComponentClick = useCallback(() => {
        onTextChange(type);
        setActiveItem((item) => !item.selected);
        console.log(item);
    }, [type]);

    const defaultColor = 'rgb(180, 180, 180)';
    const selectedItem = 'rgb(19, 186, 247)';
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onTextChange}>
```

I can get the value of the component, I display different value depending on what I click but I can't change the state value of the property. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I am going to suggest a couple of changes to how you are doing this.

I would change your initial line to:

```
const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);
```

Then in your `onClick` I would do the following:

```
const onClick = (item) => {
    setActiveItem(item.id); // Or whatever unique identifier you have in your items
    console.log(item);
};
```

Then I your `TextComponent` I would have this:

```
isActive={activeItem === item.id} // Or whatever key you used earlier
```

This way when you change it, the list will rerender and your newly selected item should be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting TextComponent deal with selected index, you can "lift the state up the parent".

The parent component maintains the current Active (Selected) item index. The children component (TextComponent) is responsible for displaying selected/unselected state and informing Parent if it has been clicked.

```
const TextComponent: React.FC<TextComponentProps> = ({
  item,
  isActive,
  onClick,
}) => {
  // Update display to selectedColor and defaultColor
  return isActive ? (
    <div onClick={onClick} className="bg-red-300"> {item} </div> 
  ) : (
    <div onClick={onClick}  className="bg-green-300"> {item} </div>
  );
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState<number>(0);

  const items = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"];

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item: string, index: number) => {
          return (
            <TextComponent
              isActive={activeItem === index}
              key={index}
              item={item}
              onClick={() => setActiveItem(index)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When TextComponent is clicked, the state ActiveIndex in the parent is updated. When the state is updated, the Parent component is re-rendered, reevaluating isActive flag for all the children.